# document.querySelector not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari

I am trying to add a javascript click event to an input field as shown below. What works is on all fields via the code below:

```
this.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    alert("hallo");
});
```

What I want is on the specific input field. Have tried the following code:

```
document.querySelector(".search-form").addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    alert("hallo");
});
```

The document.querySelector works fine on desktop though.

```html
<div class="nv-nav-search" aria-label="search">
  <div class="form-wrap ">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://www.k.nl/"><label><span class="screen-reader-text">Zoek naar...</span><input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Zoek naar..." value="" name="s"></label><input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
      <div class="nv-search-icon-wrap">
        <div class="nv-icon nv-search">
          <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1216 832q0-185-131.5-316.5t-316.5-131.5-316.5 131.5-131.5 316.5 131.5 316.5 316.5 131.5 316.5-131.5 131.5-316.5zm512 832q0 52-38 90t-90 38q-54 0-90-38l-343-342q-179 124-399 124-143 0-273.5-55.5t-225-150-150-225-55.5-273.5 55.5-273.5 150-225 225-150 273.5-55.5 273.5 55.5 225 150 150 225 55.5 273.5q0 220-124 399l343 343q37 37 37 90z"></path></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My aim is to send the user to a different url with the input which is given. The problem is one can mouse click or can click enter to perform the submit action.

The [compatability of the queryselector](https://caniuse.com/?search=queryselector) looks okay.

Comment: Have added an id but even that doesn't do the trick.

document.querySelector("#searchheader").addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchvalue = document.querySelector('.search-field').value;
    window.location.href = "/?s=" + searchvalue + "&post_type=product";
 });

Mobile is simply not able to cope with a specific element. changing it to this does work, but offcourse doesn't solve my issue.